# wxPython pdfviewer unknown font preventing pdf loading

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-viewer, wxpython

While checking out wxPython's `wx.lib.pdfViewer`, I ran [the code](https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.pdfviewer.html) in the documentation. It worked well, but most of the pdf did not load, and messages like these

```
Unknown font ghlcbg+arial
Unknown font ghlcdi+arial,bold
```

were printed. I surmise that it is because the fonts used in the pdf are not implemented by PyPDF2. How can I solve this problem? I can preprocess the pdf to replace the fonts if necessary, but this I do not know how to do either.

---

Is there a library which allows for replacement of fonts? If there is not, is there a replacement for PyPDF2 which permits this replacement (PyMuPDF does not work for me due to another error)? If such a replacement is not possible, is there an extension which permits the interpretation of such fonts?

Comment: For reference, the PyMuPDF error has something to do with invalid buffer sizes.

Comment: In my experience `wx.LaunchDefaultBrowser(url, flags=0)` does a half decent job of calling whatever is defined on your system for each file type, including pdf files.

Comment: That is a good solution, but unfortunately I am already using the system browser for the pdf, and I would like to replace that in this use case. (Unless there is a method for also closing said viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxPython cannot load a PDF that PyPDF2 does not support. I think there is talk about moving to pdfrw, but that has not occurred as of yet and I don't know if it actually has handling for unknown fonts or not. The main benefit to moving is PyPDF2 is no longer being maintained.

PyQt can do it since it integrates with poppler. See https://github.com/frescobaldi/python-poppler-qt4 or http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/qt5-poppler-pdf.html